# how to block a mac adress on debian

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, ddos

i have dos attack on server 
Jul 21 16:20:42 sip kernel: [151675.053103] Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT=eth0 MAC=00:24:21:ef:2d:5f:00:21:59:c5:74:4e:08:00 SRC=78.87.201.181 DST=188.40.114.228 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=44313 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=4858 DPT=80 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

it is possible to block mac adress on debian ? this adress 00:24:21:ef:2d:5f:00:21:59:c5:74:4e:08:00

i tested this iptables but do not work,  :
 # iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 00:24:21:ef:2d:5f:00:21:59:c5:74:4e:08:00 -j DROP              iptables v1.4.14: ether
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Comment: I think you'll get (more) help if you post this question over at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/). Stack Overflow is for programming questions only and your question is related to network administration, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
MAC=00:24:21:ef:2d:5f:00:21:59:c5:74:4e:08:00
```

This is not a single [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address). In fact this is the destination MAC, the source MAC and the frame type pieced together.

```
DEST MAC: 00:24:21:ef:2d:5f
SOURCE MAC: 00:21:59:c5:74:4e
FRAME TYPE: 08:00
```

If you really want to filter on the MAC address you can use:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 00:21:59:c5:74:4e -j DROP
```

But note that this is very likely to drop all packets comming from your router (or to what ever device that MAC address belongs to).

I would recommend to filter on the source IP address instead.